# How can I return an impl Trait where the type's reference implements the trait?

Tags: rust, types

Given the following items:

```rust
trait Trait { ... }

struct Thing { ... }

impl Trait for &Thing { ... }
```

Is it possible to write a function that returns a `Thing` but such that:

- The concrete type, `Thing`, is hidden from the consumer.
- The consumer can only access `Trait`'s methods and associated types.

In other words I almost want to return an `impl Trait`, but that wouldn't work because `Thing` doesn't implement `Trait`, only `&Thing` does.

```rust
// error: the trait bound `Thing: Trait` is not satisfied
fn get_thing() -> impl Trait {
    Thing { ... }
}
```

(Trait is actually in another crate so I can't add a blanket implementation.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, your code works if you actually return a `&Thing` [like so](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ef74021db80702bcb363c34f76714b0f). However, that really only works because static / const promotion allows you to make references to zero-sized types without worrying about ownership, which you would likely have problems with if `Thing` were more complicated.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you mean, hopefully my answer helps.

Comment: Yeah it's a shame that's there's no syntax which introduces a temporary name for an existential. In Haskell, you could do `-> forall t. Trait t => t`, which would translate into Rust something like `-> for<T> T where T: Trait`. With that you could express the constraint you wanted.

Comment: @kmdreko ah, I wasn't aware of const promotion! Yes, I meant a case where I can't just return a reference. Edited the question for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax currently to convey "I'm returning some anonymous type where the reference to that type implements some trait" unfortunately. You can however introduce your own trait to try to convey this idea:

```
trait RefTrait {
    type T<'a>: Trait where Self: 'a;
    fn as_trait(&self) -> Self::T<'_>;
}

impl<T> RefTrait for T where for<'a> &'a T: Trait {
    type T<'a> = &'a T where T: 'a;
    fn as_trait(&self) -> Self::T<'_> {
        &self
    }
}

fn get_thing() -> impl RefTrait {
    Thing
}
```

Comment: That's a good workaround, thank you. I wonder what syntax for this could look like, and if anyone's thinking about it already..?